# Export the dataGridView to Excel with all the cells format

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, excel-interop, cell-formatting

I have this code that I know that it works fast

```
CopyAlltoClipboard(dataGridViewControl);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
xlexcel.Visible = true;
xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet.Name = page.Name;
Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
CR.Select();
xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Range["A1"]).EntireColumn.Delete(null); // delete the first column that has rows indexes
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName);

private void CopyAlltoClipboard(DataGridView dataGridViewControl)
{
    dataGridViewControl.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dataGridViewControl.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
       Invoke((Action)(() => { Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj); }));
}
```

The code works fine, but it does copy only the values is the excel, doesn't copy also the cells format (wrap text, backcolor, font, borders etc)
Can anyone help me on this one? How to complete this code the have the exact format like in DataGridView?

Comment: Have you checked these: [How to keep colors when copy-pasting from datagridview to excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005721/how-to-keep-colors-when-copy-pasting-from-datagridview-to-excel) , [Datagridview to Clipboard with formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829487/datagridview-to-clipboard-with-formatting) ? There is also another one here: [Maintain DataGridView Format when exporting to Excel(C#)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f615a10a-dcb9-440c-afb0-68d296cb0361/maintain-datagridview-format-when-exporting-to-excelc?forum=exceldev)

Answer (score 15):

Update: Now available in GitHub:
https://github.com/MeaningOfLights/DataGridToHTML

---

I'm struggling to understand why this isn't a duplicate. There are [examples](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f615a10a-dcb9-440c-afb0-68d296cb0361/maintain-datagridview-format-when-exporting-to-excelc?forum=exceldev) all over the net and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765580/export-formatted-datagridview-to-excel).

**To my surprise & after a lot of research there are no thorough examples of Exporting DataGridView to HTML or Excel with formatting anywhere on the internet -** *until now :)*

Looking at this code in your question you have found out how slow it is to copy large datasets with Interop and have opted to use the Clipboard instead:

```
dataGridViewControl.SelectAll();
DataObject dataObj = dataGridViewControl.GetClipboardContent();
if (dataObj != null)
    Invoke((Action)(() => { Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj); }));
```

> The crux of this question is - using the Clipboard on a DataGridView does not contain the Cell Formatting. Because the clipboard doesn't contain the formatting you're back to the original slow performance problem of having to set Cell Styles individually, which using Interop is very, very slow.

In this case it might work better to create Excel files using **XML instead of Interop**. So while I first thought this would be a good workaround and the other answer here by DartAlex demonstrates that, I thought I'd code up an answer you can use with the Clipboard method. Getting a **HTML Copy of the DataGridView** *with formatting* and pasting that into Excel:

**DataGridView To HTML Table with Formatting and then into Excel**

[image]

```
//====================================================
//DataGridView Export To HTML by Jeremy Thompson: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210329/
//====================================================
public string ConvertDataGridViewToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //create html & table
    sb.AppendLine("<html><body><center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>");
    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
    //create table header
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(DGVHeaderCellToHTMLWithFormatting(dgv, i));
        sb.Append(DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText, dgv.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Font));
        sb.AppendLine("</td>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
    //create table body
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgv.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
        foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(DGVCellToHTMLWithFormatting(dgv, rowIndex, dgvc.ColumnIndex));
            string cellValue = dgvc.Value == null ? string.Empty : dgvc.Value.ToString();
            sb.AppendLine(DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(cellValue, dgvc.Style.Font));
            sb.AppendLine("</td>");
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
    }
    //table footer & end of html file
    sb.AppendLine("</table></center></body></html>");
    return sb.ToString();
}

//TODO: Add more cell styles described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0(v=vs.110).aspx
public string DGVHeaderCellToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv, int col)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<td");
    sb.Append(DGVCellColorToHTML(dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor, dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor));
    sb.Append(DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(dgv.Columns[col].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment));
    sb.Append(">");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellToHTMLWithFormatting(DataGridView dgv, int row, int col)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<td");
    sb.Append(DGVCellColorToHTML(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.ForeColor, dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.BackColor));
    sb.Append(DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.Alignment));
    sb.Append(">");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellColorToHTML(Color foreColor, Color backColor)
{
    if (foreColor.Name == "0" && backColor.Name == "0") return string.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" style=\"");
    if (foreColor.Name != "0" && backColor.Name != "0")
    {
        sb.Append("color:#");
        sb.Append(foreColor.R.ToString("X2") + foreColor.G.ToString("X2") + foreColor.B.ToString("X2"));
        sb.Append("; background-color:#");
        sb.Append(backColor.R.ToString("X2") + backColor.G.ToString("X2") + backColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }
    else if (foreColor.Name != "0" && backColor.Name == "0")
    {
        sb.Append("color:#");
        sb.Append(foreColor.R.ToString("X2") + foreColor.G.ToString("X2") + foreColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }
    else //if (foreColor.Name == "0" &&  backColor.Name != "0")
    {
        sb.Append("background-color:#");
        sb.Append(backColor.R.ToString("X2") + backColor.G.ToString("X2") + backColor.B.ToString("X2"));
    }

    sb.Append(";\"");
    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellFontAndValueToHTML(string value,Font font)
{
    //If no font has been set then assume its the default as someone would be expected in HTML or Excel
    if (font == null || font == this.Font && !(font.Bold | font.Italic | font.Underline | font.Strikeout)) return value;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" ");
    if (font.Bold) sb.Append("<b>");
    if (font.Italic) sb.Append("<i>");
    if (font.Strikeout) sb.Append("<strike>");
    
    //The <u> element was deprecated in HTML 4.01. The new HTML 5 tag is: text-decoration: underline
    if (font.Underline) sb.Append("<u>");
    
    string size = string.Empty;
    if (font.Size != this.Font.Size) size = "font-size: " + font.Size + "pt;";

    //The <font> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS or a span instead. 
    if (font.FontFamily.Name != this.Font.Name)
    {
        sb.Append("<span style=\"font-family: ");
        sb.Append(font.FontFamily.Name);
        sb.Append("; ");
        sb.Append(size);
        sb.Append("\">");
    }
    sb.Append(value);
    if (font.FontFamily.Name != this.Font.Name) sb.Append("</span>");

    if (font.Underline) sb.Append("</u>");
    if (font.Strikeout) sb.Append("</strike>");
    if (font.Italic) sb.Append("</i>");
    if (font.Bold) sb.Append("</b>");

    return sb.ToString();
}

public string DGVCellAlignmentToHTML(DataGridViewContentAlignment align)
{
    if (align == DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet) return string.Empty;

    string horizontalAlignment = string.Empty;
    string verticalAlignment = string.Empty;
    CellAlignment(align, ref horizontalAlignment, ref verticalAlignment);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" align='");
    sb.Append(horizontalAlignment);
    sb.Append("' valign='");
    sb.Append(verticalAlignment);
    sb.Append("'");
    return sb.ToString();
}

private void CellAlignment(DataGridViewContentAlignment align, ref string horizontalAlignment, ref string verticalAlignment)
{
    switch (align)
    {
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
            horizontalAlignment = "centre";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "top";
            break;
        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
            horizontalAlignment = "right";
            verticalAlignment = "bottom";
            break;

        default: //DataGridViewContentAlignment.NotSet
            horizontalAlignment = "left";
            verticalAlignment = "middle";
            break;
    }
}


//Easy repro - copy/paste all this code in a Winform app!
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", ""), "testData.csv");
    List<string[]> rows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(configFile).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("testing");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("one");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("two");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("three");
    rows.ForEach(x => { dataTable.Rows.Add(x); });
    this.dgv.DataSource = dataTable;

    dgv.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout); 

    dgv[0, 0].Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    dgv[1, 0].Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight;
    dgv[2, 0].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Calibri"),(float)16);
    dgv[3, 0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    
    dgv[0, 1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    dgv[1, 1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font,  FontStyle.Underline);
    dgv[2, 1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
    dgv[3, 1].Style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
    dgv[3, 1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    dgv[3, 1].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    dgv[0, 2].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"), (float)18);
    dgv[1, 2].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Georgia"), (float)12);
    dgv[2, 2].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Arial"), (float)14);
    dgv[3, 2].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Verdana"), (float)18);

    dgv[0, 3].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Courier New"), (float)11);
    dgv[1, 3].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Lucida Console"), (float)18);
    dgv[2, 3].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Times"), (float)14);
    dgv[3, 3].Style.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("serif"), (float)12);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dgvToHTMLTable = ConvertDataGridViewToHTMLWithFormatting(dgv);
    Clipboard.SetText(dgvToHTMLTable);
}
```

**TestData.csv:**

> Magic,Abra,Cadabra,Boom!
> Coding,Fun,YeeHaa,ABS TableName
> Hello,world,Population.html,TABLE 1.
> Demography,310102.xls,Comp.html,TABLE 2.

Comment: This works well for most cases, but it fails on data which is text that is all numeric.  A string such as "0814180649644754" ends up displayed as 8.14181E+14 and the value is converted to a number (dropping the critical leading 0). Adding a single quote to force a string is also unacceptable, since in our case, these values are rendered into barcodes and the additional character is a problem.  This solution, which works well for formatting, does not handle datatypes as well as it should.

Comment: That's how Excel works https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983731/495455.  If you want to use large numbers you'll have to enclose in qoutes. Unacceptable is subjective, remove the quote before you render it. Also note the code is open source for people to contribute additional features, such as quoting fields with large numbers starting with zero or providing a datatype column mapper. Nevertheless if you're programmatically or manually doing this in both cases you can add and strip quotes and format cells..

Answer (score 3):

The crux of your question is using the Clipboard on a DataGridView does not contain Cell Formatting. Because the Clipboard doesn't contain the formatting you're back to the original slow performance problem of having to set Cell Styles individually, which using Interop is very, very slow.

In this case it will work better to create Excel files using XML instead of Interop. Below is a method using [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) to export a DataGridView to Excel with formatting.

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

public void ExportToExcelWithFormatting(DataGridView dataGridView1)
{
    string fileName;

    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "xls files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "To Excel";
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = this.Text + " (" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ")";

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(this.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cell(1, i + 1).Value = dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                if (worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    XLAlignmentHorizontalValues align;

                    switch (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Alignment)
                    {
                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                            break;
                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                            break;
                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                            break;

                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                            break;
                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                            break;
                        case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                            break;

                        default:
                            align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
                            break;
                    }

                    worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = align;

                    XLColor xlColor = XLColor.FromColor(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.SelectionBackColor);
                    worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).AddConditionalFormat().WhenLessThan(1).Fill.SetBackgroundColor(xlColor);

                    worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Style.Font.FontName = dataGridView1.Font.Name;
                    worksheet.Cell(i + 2, j + 1).Style.Font.FontSize = dataGridView1.Font.Size;

                }                                           
            }
        }
        worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        workbook.SaveAs(fileName);
        //MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found a solution using interop and EPPlus. I used the code above only to copy the values in Excel and then use this code below (EPPlus code) to take the format from dataGridView.
This code depends or what you want to take from the dataGridView. In this code below I wanted to take the WrapText from the first row and the background colors from each written cell

```
private void FinalizeWorkbook(DataTableReportParam reportParam, DataGridView dataGridViewControl)
{
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(reportParam.FileName);
    ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
    IWorksheet worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    // wrap text and color the crashes with problems (header)
    for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
    {
        worksheet[1, col].WrapText = true;
        worksheet[1, col].AutofitRows();
        if (String.Compare(dataGridViewControl[col - 1, 0].Style.BackColor.Name, "0") != 0)
            worksheet[1, col].CellStyle.Color = dataGridViewControl[col - 1, 0].Style.BackColor;
    }

    // color the cells
    for (int row = 2; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
        {
            if (String.Compare(dataGridViewControl[col - 1, row - 1].Style.BackColor.Name, "0") != 0)
                worksheet[row, col].CellStyle.Color = dataGridViewControl[col - 1, row - 1].Style.BackColor;
        }
    }
    //save and dispose
    pck.Save();
    pck.Dispose();
}
```