# Exporting a DataGridView to Excel with filters applied c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I have some code which successfully exports a `DataGridView` to an excel spreadsheet from my program. However, when a filter is applied to the `grid` it exports just the headers and no data.

The code which is actually writing the data is below:

```
// storing header part in Excel  
 for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView_assets.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
 {
     worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView_assets.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
 }

 // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_assets.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView_assets.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView_assets.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
     }
 }
```

The code I used to add the filters to my data are below:

```
DataView typeFilter = new DataView(allAssetsDT, filter, "[Barcode] ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    dataGridView_assets.DataSource = typeFilter;
```

Is there a way to only export the data which is still viewed when a filter is applied?

EDIT: With using the answer given I now have issues with the following lines of code:

```
worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dtFiltered.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
```

The issue with the above is the .HeaderText.

```
worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dtFiltered.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
```

The issues with the above are to do with the .Cells call. I'm guessing I need to use slightly different methods now due to changing the way this is being done?

Comment: See my update to get the headers and work with the filtered DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the DataView.

Make `typeFilter` a private member variable in scope.

Then when you export to excel, don't use the `dataGridView_assets`, use a filtered DataTable from the DataView like this:

```
DataTable dtFiltered = typeFilter.ToTable();
```

Tips: You should NOT be exporting Cell by Cell, that is very slow. Instead export all cells in one go, eg:  [Excel Interop - Efficiency and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance)

You can do that (all cells at once) with a DataGridView with this question, if you need Formatting you can use the answer: [Export the dataGridView to Excel with all the cells format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210329/export-the-datagridview-to-excel-with-all-the-cells-format)

To use your existing code with the DataTable:

```
// storing header part in Excel 
int i=0;
foreach (DataColumn dc in dtFiltered.Columns)
{
    i++;
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dc.ColumnName);
}

int j=1;
foreach (DataRow dr in dtFiltered.Rows) 
{ 
   j++;
   for (i = 0; i < dtFiltered.Columns.Count; i++)              
   { 
       worksheet.Cells[j, i + 1] =  dr[i].ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I guessing from your answer that I will need to create the ToDataTable() method? As my typeFilter is a DataView which doesn't contain a definition for .ToDataTable()

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing on my phone, it's `ToTable` as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I should have jumped on a PC to do it, freehand is hard. Tip, if you find yourself doing I + 2, j - 3 type stuff use constants or arrange it simpler, as a habit for readability later :)

Comment: I had to set i to = 1, when stepping through the columns to get it working and placing the data in the correct place. Not sure why it was needed but it works

Comment: @JeremyThompson please can you give an example of using this `DataTable dtFiltered = typeFilter.ToTable(); coz you are 100% right about looping thanks alot