# Export Excel Range to DataGridView maintaining cell formatting and formulas

Tags: c#, excel, csv, spire, spire.xls

I'm working with Spire.XLS and I have to populate an excel file with different sheets, then the problem begins, I need to take out values from different sheets and export those together in the same dataGridView, to take the values I use the method `sheet.Range[]`, it seems like spire.XLS as the command `exportDataTable()`, but in this case it shows something like this

[image]

And the problem with this one is that this doesn't maintain the cell background color nor the actual value of the formula in the last col, I'm open to other libraries as well if needed, but I need to figure this problem out

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/39314154/495455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method to export Excel formatting to DataGridView, you may write plenty of code to translate the Excel formatting to a DataGridView. If you want to export the actual value of the formula instead of the formula itself, you can use the **[ExportDataTable(CellRange range, bool exportColumnNames, bool computedFormulaValue)](https://www.e-iceblue.com/apireference/net/Spire.XLS/html/M_Spire_Xls_Worksheet_ExportDataTable_2.htm)** method.

Here is a basic example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xlsx");

    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        
    DataTable dt = sheet.ExportDataTable(sheet.Range, true, true);
        
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = sheet.Rows[0].Style.Color;
}
```

The input Excel:

[image]

The output DataGridView:
[image]

Comment: There is a way, stackoverflow.com/a/39314154/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thanks Jeremy. I meant there is no direct method to export Excel formmatting to DataGridView in the library, the OP needs to write some code to translate the Excel formmating to a DataGridView. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, the problem with the value of the formulas was easy to overcome, since Spire.XLS has a `sheet.Range[].formulaNumericValue` that collect the result of the formula, the color one I wrote the code the same day to set it in the specific range, but either way thanks a lot!